# Webpack settings to different type of import of scss file in tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, import

I am adding one small react javascript to existing react typescript project.
There are some settings which doesn't allow to import scss file directly to tsx file.

below import has been used in exsiting typescript project for scss file

```
import styles from './styles.scss'
```

I want to use the import like below

```
import './styles.scss'
```

Is there some setting I can change in webpack or packages json file which allow me to import like `'import './styles.scss'` **OR** is there any setting which allow both the import statement valid.

Comment: The first import statement above is if you’re using style modules (applying them to html/react elements): ```<div className={styles.someClassName}>...</div>```. The second import statement is if you’re using global styles (applying via strings): ```<div className=“someClassName”>...</div>```. Usually they’ll be separated/defined by an extension: `module.css` and `.css`. This way, you can have two separate Webpack rules to handle global and local (module) css imports. Unfortunately, Webpack isn’t smart enough to differentiate the two types of styles by just the import.

Comment: So to answer your question: Yes you can import both ways, but you need to add separate rules for local and global style imports. In addition, you’ll also need to use some sort of file naming extension to separate them. For further help, please post your current Webpack configuration for development and production environments.